# How can I delete a group of rows if they don't satisfy a condition?

Tags: pandas, python-2.7, dataframe, filter, rows

I have a dataframe with stock option information. I want to filter this dataframe in order to have exactly 8 options per date. The problem is that some dates have only 6 or 7 options. I want to write a code where I delete entirely this group of options.[The option dataframe that I want to filter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PRjtH.png)

Take this small dataframe as an example:

```
dates = ['2013-01-01','2013-01-01','2013-01-01','2013-01-02','2013-01-02','2013-01-03','2013-01-03','2013-01-03']
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(8, 4), index=dates, columns=list('ABCD'))
```

In this particular case I want to drop the rows indexed in date '2013-01-02' since I only want dates who have 3 consecutive rows.

Comment: Is there any way that you could share equivalent dataframe in which we could work on?

Comment: What is the criteria for deletion?

Comment: dates = ['2013-01-01','2013-01-01','2013-01-01','2013-01-02','2013-01-02','2013-01-03','2013-01-03','2013-01-03']
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(8, 4), index=dates, columns=list('ABCD'))

Comment: in this small dataframe i want to delete the two rows '2013-01-02' since i want only the dates that have 3 consecutive rows

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First group by count on index

```
odf = df.groupby(df.index).count()
```

filter the dataframe and get the resulting index

```
idx = odf[odf['A'] == 3].index
```

select by index

```
df.loc[idx]
```

Comment: did you follow [this guide](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235), because I dont see a green badge on this answer

Comment: I am sorry! I am new to this. Now its properly accepted. Thank you one more time